# stackoverflowerror on Constructor

Tags: java, constructor, stack-overflow

I am a new programmer and I can't handle errors very well.
So this thing happened:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at List.<init>(List.java:23)
    at ST.<init>(ST.java:48)
    at List.<init>(List.java:23)
    at ST.<init>(ST.java:48)
    at List.<init>(List.java:23)
    at ST.<init>(ST.java:48)
    at List.<init>(List.java:23)
    at ST.<init>(ST.java:48)
    at List.<init>(List.java:23)
    at ST.<init>(ST.java:48)
    at List.<init>(List.java:23)
    at ST.<init>(ST.java:48)
    ....
```

And it goes on for ever.
I am trying this line of code:48. `List stopwordslist=new List("Stopwords");`

And here is the whole `List class:

```
public class List extends ST {  

private ListNode firstNode;
public String ListName;

public List(String name){
    ListName=name;
    firstNode=null;
}
public void putWord(String word){
    ListNode node = new ListNode(word);
    if ( firstNode==null ) 
        firstNode = node;
    else { 
        node.nextNode =firstNode;
        firstNode.prevNode=node;
        firstNode = node;
    }
}
public void removeWord(String word) throws NoSuchElementException{
    if ( firstNode==null) 
        throw new NoSuchElementException( ListName );
    if ( firstNode.nextNode==null && firstNode.stopWord.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
    firstNode= null;
    else
    {
        ListNode current = firstNode;
        while ( current.nextNode != null )
            if (current.nextNode.stopWord.equalsIgnoreCase(word)){
            current.nextNode = current.nextNode.nextNode;
            if (current.nextNode.nextNode!=null) current.nextNode.nextNode.prevNode=current;                
            }
            else current=current.nextNode;

    } 
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Add more details about `List`.

Comment: Can you also post `ST`?

Comment: ST is 400 lines of code...

Comment: The best way here would be narrowing down ST until you get the smallest code that produces the same error, then post here. Members and constructors will probably enough in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have member variables declared in which List constructs an ST and ST also constructs a List. Even though your List constructor doesn't show the creation of an ST, if it's a member variable which creates an ST, it is effectively added to the top of the constructor. Do you have something like..

```
class ST {
    List stopwordslist=new List("Stopwords");

    …

class List {
    ST st = new ST();

    public List(String name) {
         ListName=name;
         firstNode=null;
    }
```

this is equivalent to…

```
class List {
    ST st;

    public List(String name) {
         st = new ST();
         ListName=name;
         firstNode=null;
    }
```

Ok.. iv seen your updated question.

List extends ST. So the constructor of ST looks like it's also constructing a List (which constructs List, which constructs ST etc etc)

Comment: Neither List or ListNode classes contain a ST object declaration.

Comment: Ok.. iv seen your updated question.

List extends ST. So the constructor of ST looks like it's also constructing a List (which constructs List, which contracts ST etc etc)

Comment: Yes. That was the case. Thank you very much. Have a nice day!
#iLoveSkilledPeople